# Enumerate class members in Swift

Tags: swift, class, sprite-kit, member, skshapenode

I'm working with Swift and SpriteKit

I have a class :

```
class Button: SKShapeNode
{
}
```

And I have some buttons:

```
var button1 = Button()
var button2 = Button()
```

And I already use the ".name" of those nodes :

```
button1.name = "button1"
button2.name = "button2"
```

So normally, I enumerate thoses nodes with `enumerateChildNodesWithName("button")` but here, the name is already taken, so how could I enumerate all of my buttons (that use the class Button) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate all the child nodes of a given node by calling `enumerateChildNodesWithName` with `//*` as the node name. This is listed as an example in Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013023-CH1-SW74).

Then in the block check to see if the node is of type `Button` and perform your action accordingly.

So something like this:

```
myNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("//*") { node, ptr in
    if node is Button {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this method ! And why are you using `ptr` ? I always use `_`, what does it change ?

Comment: The second argument in the closure is a pointer to a boolean variable that can be set to true to terminate the enumeration early. If you don't intend on using the second argument, ignoring it with an `_` is the best practice. In your case you want to search through all the nodes, so you don't need to terminate early.

Comment: You can also use the `.children` property instead of `enumerateChildNodesWithName`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `children` property of the node:

`var buttonNodes = node.children.filter { $0 is Button }`

Complete example:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

let node = SKNode()

class Button: SKNode {
}

let button1 = Button()
let button2 = Button()
let label = SKLabelNode()

node.addChild(button1)
node.addChild(button2)
node.addChild(label)

let buttons = node.children.filter { $0 is Button }
print(buttons.count) // buttons only has 2 elements, the button nodes!
```